# Screen Randomly turning off

Tags: suspend, screen

So I recently installed Ubuntu onto my Surface Pro 1, and have been running fine for about 2 days, until today I saw the screen constantly turning off, as if it were inactive for the set time and turning the screen off. I would then just have to tap the power button and it would come back on and then about 20 seconds later turn back off. This used to only happen after the system was suspended, and I would just have to restart to fix it, but now it is happening all the time and making it un usable. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the problem by updating the file `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to include the following:

`HandleLidSwitch=ignore`

Comment: This saved me. Unfortunately, this was on a workstation with no LID.

Answer (score 1):

This is a real shot in the dark....

I came across this bug report today: [LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=no](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=366402) where systemd was automatically suspending the laptop for no reason and I remembered your post from 2 days ago. The Surface Pro also has a lid close switch.

Type `gksu gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf` in the terminal. And search for this line:

```
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
```

Remove the **#** and change the **yes** to **no**.

Save the file, reboot and let me know if it changes anything.

Comment: Alright I did it, it has been less frequent, and this makes sense that the keyboard is moving around a little and detecting a lid close. So ill see if it still happens sometimes. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If it's is successful please mark it as solved so others know they can do the same fix. If it's not successful, well nothing ventured, nothing gained and it was worth a shot.