# Laptop display shutting off on hinge adjustment

Tags: xubuntu, display, laptop, asus

So this is a pretty bizarre issue I have had for a while now. When I adjust the hinge angle of my laptop screen sometimes the display will turn off. Also sometimes the display will go off even when not touched, but this is more rare. The laptop does not go to sleep. Other external displays continue operating normally.

So far the only work-arounds I have found are putting the computer to sleep and waking it back up or switching to a different TTY (1-6) then back to the x environment (7). Another solution that works sometimes is connecting/disconnecting an external display so that the display resets.

Is there any kind of fix or workaround to prevent this? I have tried [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823124/screen-randomly-turning-off/824199#824199). But it did not solve the problem for me.

I am running Xubuntu 17.04 on an Asus N550-JX

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem. Does the same thing happen in Windows? Do you get the same problem when booted from a LiveUSB?

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have other OSs installed to test with, I have tried a live USB and it did appear to continue so I figured it was a hardware issue but I wanted to know if there was some kind of way the software could ignore the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

## This is a hardware problem

As the problem continues with LiveUSB as well as installed Ubuntu, we know that the lid switch is probably broken or there is a loose connection to the display.

## Try this

Click on the **battery icon** on the top right corner and select **Power Settings**.

Change the option of **When the lid is closed** to **Do nothing** for both "On battery power"  and "When plugged in".

I don't know if this will work around the problem, but its worth a shot.

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately I only have options for Switch off display, Suspend, and Lock Screen. I would have tried this earlier but I have suspend selected and the issue isn't the laptop going to sleep but the laptop display turning off.

Comment: I am sorry, I have no other ideas. Best of luck.