# Laptop automatically suspending after lid closed and reopened

Tags: suspend, laptop, lid

**My current kernel version**

```
Linux xorist-Blade-Stealth 4.18.0-041800-generic #201808122131 SMP Sun Aug 12 21:33:20 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**The issue I'm having**

First I feel it's important to note that I am working with a freshly installed version of Ubuntu, the only thing I've done to it was update the kernel. This update to the kernel could NOT be directly related to the issue I'm having because it existed prior to the update.

Whenever I boot my laptop it will work perfectly fine until I close the lid, wait for it to suspend, reopen it and let it wake back up. After I have done this process and it's in the normal awakened state, about 15-30 seconds will pass before it automatically suspends itself.

If I press the power button to wake it back up and log in again, it will continue to automatically suspend itself after about the same period of 15-30 seconds. This problem persists until I completely reboot my laptop.

I've attempted all of the answers under [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/823124/screen-randomly-turning-off) post, but none helped.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this issue?

**edit**

This is the result of running cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
#KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=yes
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
#UserTasksMax=33%
```

Comment: tell me how you sets your lid with type `cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf` and please edit question with that output.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't tested to see if my case is similar to yours in that aspect. I'll scrounge up what other info I can when I am home.

Comment: I posted an answer a couple of days ago. Now it's shortened considerably. Please give it a second look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First thing to try

Use `sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf` and search for this line:

```
#HandlLidSwitch=
```

change it to:

```
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```

Then save the file and reboot.

Comment: That fixed it! the only problem I have now though, is that when I close the lid it appears to only sleep the screen and the computer doesn't hibernate in any way?

Comment: I've never setup hibernation but you have two types. 1. Hibernate immediately. 2. Hibernate after sleeping for a certain period. So you need to pick one. Secondly you need to have a swap disk (possibly just swap file) setup that is large enough to hold RAM that is being used. On large RAM systems that usually means the Swap file has to be 3/5th of RAM. There is a directory/file that shows minimum swap size and it is best to have a little more set aside: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/swap and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate

Answer (score 0):

It is matter of system settings ... ?!

Goto "system settings" in your desktop menue. Then go there to "energy". There you can set following :

switch off the screen - to: "never"

automatic setting to standby - to: "off"

when switch-off key - to: "nothing"

This should be the solution.

(Reboot your machine and all should be fine.)

You can close the lid of your laptop and it is still ready for action, as soon as you open the lid - only the screen is off but not suspending.

Comment: I don't appear to have an "energy" option in my system settings.

Comment: @xorist - look in system-settings where you can adjust behaviour of scrennsaver and of suspending time. in German it is there in "energy settings". my solution works here too.

Comment: I looked further into your solution and I found what you were talking about under "Power Settings", but unfortunately it didn't solve my issue. @WinEunuuchs2Unix posted the solution that worked for my case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old question, but having fixed the same issue myself I feel that I should post the solution here.

The kernel parameter `button.lid_init_state=open` has fixed the issue for me, on Fedora, Arch, and Ubuntu, while allowing the laptop to still suspend when the lid is closed. Put this in /etc/default/grub, and run update-grub